# JavaArray Index out of Bounds exception w/ for loop

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting an array index out of bounds exception while iterating over an array through the for-loop. Can someone tell me why this is happening it I have set the boolean in the for-loop to be i

```
public static boolean verify(int [] seq ){
  for (int i=0; i<seq.length; i++){

  //If the number is even, the next number
  //must the half the previous number
  if (seq[i] %2==0){
    if (seq[i+1] != (seq[i]/2)){
      return false;
    }
  }

  //If the number is positive, the next number
  //must be 3 times + 1 the previous number
  else if (seq[i] %2!=0){
    if (seq[i+1] != ((seq[i])*3+1)){
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you print out the value of `i` at every step? Or better yet, use a debugger.

Comment: can't call `seq[i+1]` when `i=seq.length`.  Change loop condition to `i<seq.length-1`

Comment: You can't use `seq[i+1]` when `i+1` >= `seq.length`

Comment: "I have set the boolean in the for-loop to be i" you have WHAT?

Comment: This is a good opportunity to learn how to debug.  If you don't have an effective debugger, use println statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you access index `i+1`.  If `i` is the last possible value (`seq.length - 1`), then `i+1` is one beyond the end of the array, resulting in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Stop your `for` loop one iteration earlier by modifying your condition to be:

```
i < seq.length - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You will face exception for the maximum value of `i` bcoz you are increasing the value by 1 to find the index value.

```
    if (seq[i] %2==0){
            if (seq[i+1] != (seq[i]/2)){
---------------------^
              return false;
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access position `i+1` or the `Array`. Since your for loop goes until the last element, you'll try to access 1 position after the last element, what causes the `Out Of Bounds` exception.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over all elements in the array, but checking element `seq[i + 1]` for `i == seq.lenth - 1` will always cause the exception. The last number is fully constrained by your conditions, so no need to check it. Make your loop run as follows: `for (int i=0; i  <seq.length - 1; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
    if (seq[i+1] != (seq[i]/2)) {
```

cannot access an element beyond the end of the array, when `i` is `seq.length - 1`.

Another line like that is down in the else branch.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite obvious , when you are passing an array (i.e. array contains 10 elements) and operating inside loop that correct.But when you are accessing `seq[i+1]` , there might be the you are accessing the index which is not available in the array.

When the `i` value reaches at 10 and you are trying to access `i+1` , but this index is not in array (as we know array size is 10)

So , its caused this exception.
Hope it will help you.